# Grails, can't persist object in a while inside a for (object class with composite id)

Tags: excel, grails, while-loop, persistence, composite-key

I'm reading an Excel file with a 'for loop'. And I have no problem persisting 3 different instances of different classes that represents the firsts set of columns in the excel file.

But when I try to "while-loop" the next columns that represent a dynamic range of other objects I can't get them to persist in the DB. Nor with flush:true or anything.

```
for (int r = 6; r < sheet.rows; r++) 
{ 
  def fooInstance = new Foo()
  def barInstance = new Bar()
  def fooBarInstance = new FooBar()

  //Set foo, bar and fooBar Instances properties based on the excel columns
  def bazIndez = 11
  while(bazIndex < sheet.columns){
     def bazInstance = new Baz()
     //set bazInstance properties
     println bazInstance //Every property is ok
     println bazInstance.getErrors() //0 errors
     bazInstance.save() // .save(flush:true) didn't work either
     bazIndez++
     }

  foo.save()     //No problem here
  bar.save()     //No problem here
  fooBar.save()  //No problem here
}
```

fooInstance, barInstance and fooBarInstance get persisted, but bazInstance never is.

Note 1: All these object have no relationship with each other or with any other class.

Note 2: All these objects use composite id and "id generator: 'assigned'"

Grails 1.3.9
JDK 1.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe you can call `getErrors()` without first validating, as validation is what populates the list of errors. Try running `bazInstance.validate()` before checking for errors.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) that shows you what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks!, you're absolutely right. I Did not know that validate() was necesary for errors to show. I thought I used getErrors() without validate() before, but I must been confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, may I leave it as an answer?

Comment: Gonna leave this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can call `getErrors()` without first validating, as validation is what populates the list of errors.

Try running `bazInstance.validate()` before checking for errors. That should display any validation errors that are preventing the domain class from persisting.